# How can I use DefinitelyTyped types in JSDoc without package.json in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I'm working on a JavaScript-only (no typescript, no package.json) project.

I usually get VSCode IntelliSense to work with JSDoc. However, I'm using CDNs and minified versions of libraries that already have JSDoc, flow or typescript types either on their own package or in DefinitelyTyped.

How can I import the type info to add to a javascript file and allow VSCode IntelliSense to do its job? (without the use of npm, yarn, package.json, tsconfig.json, only raw .js/.html files)

Is there something like a [triple-slash directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) I could use to point to an URL?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the DefinitelyTyped library and then using ///<reference path="..." /> to target the .d.ts file locally?

Comment: @Balah havent! gonna try it